# How to filter sqarewave function with varying amplitude and offset using scipy?

Tags: filter, scipy, fft

I have next signal: [Figure of squarewave of varying amplitude and offset with noises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHUQ2.png)

How can I get rid of the noise and get something like shown on figure below. May be more sqarewaved.
[Figure how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsNRy.png)
The code below can only retrieve offset changes periodicity. [Figure of FFT results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoHon.png)

```
sig=sig[1000:3500]
time_step=1
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
sig_fft = fftpack.fft(sig)

# And the power (sig_fft is of complex dtype)
power = np.abs(sig_fft)**2

# The corresponding frequencies
sample_freq = fftpack.fftfreq(sig.size,d=time_step)
print(sample_freq)
# Plot the FFT power
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
plt.plot(sample_freq, power)
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('plower')

pos_mask = np.where(sample_freq > 0)
freqs = sample_freq[pos_mask]
peak_freq = freqs[power[pos_mask].argmax()]
high_freq_fft = sig_fft.copy()
high_freq_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) > peak_freq] = 0
filtered_sig = fftpack.ifft(high_freq_fft)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
plt.plot( sig, label='Original signal')
plt.plot( filtered_sig, linewidth=3, label='Filtered signal')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than trying to play with inverse FFT which is kinda low-level, it might be easier to just use e.g. a Butterworth filter. See `scipy.signal.butter()` and `scipy.signal.filter()`

Comment: Could you include some data generation code to make your script reproducible?